# Cakephp caching assotiation result

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, caching, model

I'm querying big chunks of data with cachephp's find. I use recursive 2. (I really need that much recursion sadly.) I want to cache the result from associations, but I don't know where to return them. For example I have a *Card table* and card belongs to Artist. When I query something from Card, the find method runs in the *Card table*, but not in the *Artist table*, but I get the Artist value for the Card's artist_id field and I see a query in the query log like this:

```
`Artist`.`id`, `Artist`.`name` FROM `swords`.`artists` AS `Artist` WHERE `Artist`.`id` = 93
```

My question is how can I cache this type of queries?

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to cache query or query returned data?

Comment: The returned data. So when a new query is going out with the same id I can just return the data from the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Where does Cake "do" this?

CakePHP does this really cool but - as you have discovered yourself - sometimes expensive operation in its different `DataSource::read()` Method implementations. For example in the Dbo Datasources its [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php#L1035). As you can see, you have no direct 'hooks' (= callbacks) at the point where Cake determines the value of the `$recursive` option and may decides to query your associations. BUT we have `before` and `after` callbacks.

## 2. Where to Cache the associated Data?

Such an operation is in my opinion best suited in the `beforeFind` and `afterFind` callback method of your `Model` classes *OR* equivalent with `Model.beforeFind` and `Model.afterFind` event listeners attached to the models event manager.

The general idea is to check your Cache in the `beforeFind` method. If you have some data cached, **change** the `$recursive` option to a lower value (e.g. -1, 0 or 1) and do the normal query. In the `afterFind` method, you merge your cached data with the newly fetched data from your database.

Note that `beforeFind` is *only* called on the Model from which you are actually fetching the data, whereas `afterFind` is also called on every associated Model, thus the `$primary` parameter.

## 3. An Example?

```php
// We are in a Model.
protected $cacheKey;

public function beforeFind($query) {
    if (isset($query["recursive"]) && $query["recursive"] == 2) {
        $this->cacheKey = genereate_my_unique_query_cache_key($query); // Todo
        if (Cache::read($this->cacheKey) !== false) {
            $query["recursive"] = 0; // 1, -1, ...
            return $query;
        }
    }

    return parent::beforeFind($query);
}

public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    if ($primary && $this->cacheKey) {
        if (($cachedData = Cache::read($this->cacheKey)) !== false) {
            $results = array_merge($results, $cachedData);
            // Maybe use Hash::merge() instead of array_merge
            // or something completely different.
        } else {
            $data = ...;
            // Extract your data from $results here,
            // Hash::extract() is your friend!
            // But use debug($results) if you have no clue :)
            Cache::write($this->cacheKey, $data);
        }
        $this->cacheKey = null;
    }

    return parent::afterFind($results, $primary);
}
```

## 4. What else?

If you are having trouble with deep / high values of `$recursion`, have a look into Cake's [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). This allows you to filter even the deepest recursions.

As another tip: sometimes such deep recursions *can* be a sign of a general *bad* or *suboptimal* design (Database Schema, general Software Architecture, Process and Functional flow of the Appliaction, and so on). Maybe there is an easier way to achieve your desired result?

Comment: This was a really deep answer, thanks! I'll award the bounty for you but can't at the moment. (Need 4 more hours.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to install the [CakePHP Autocache Plugin](https://github.com/ndejong/CakephpAutocachePlugin).

I've been using this (with several custom modifications) for the last 6 months, and it works extremely well.  It will not only cache the recursive data as you want, but also any other model query.  It can bring the number of queries per request to zero, and still be able to invalidate its cache when the data changes.  It's the holy grail of caching... ad-hoc solutions aren't anywhere near as good as this plugin.

Comment: Which version of cakePHP have you installed? Because I have 2.5.6 and the plugin doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Write query result like following

```
Cache::write("cache_name",$result);
```

When you want to retrieve data from cache then write like

```
$results = Cache::read("cache_name");
```

Comment: My main problem is that I don't know where does I want to return something from the cache. The problem is that the query to the Artist table is issued by cake itself because of the 'recursive => 2' directive in the find method. I don't want to cache the result of the find, but cache the result of the belongsTo queries issued by cake when fetching my find. Sadly I don't know where does cake issue those queries.